Hover Popup Issues in Slick Slider
I'm using the Slick slider for a carousel, and each slide contains dynamic content that includes a hover popup. The problem arises because Slick slider elements have overflow: hidden by default, which cuts off the hover popup. To ensure the hover popup displays correctly, I need to place it within the slide element.

However, when I remove overflow: hidden, the hover popup displays correctly but introduces unwanted horizontal scrolling in the slider. This scrolling issue disrupts the layout and user experience.
How to maintain the hover popup functionality without causing horizontal scrolling?
Tried to remove overflow: hidden (it works, but facing horizontal scroll issue)
